# Почему обрезается правая и нижняя граница прямоугольника в svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Появилась проблема с бордерами в svg (писал руками).
Если вставлять напрямую в HTML с помощью тега `<svg></svg>` все отображается нормально и бордеры в том числе.
 Когда я выношу этот svg в отдельный файл и запускаю в браузере опять все отображается нормально.
 Но когда вставляю этот svg в html с помощью тега `<img />` как бы обрезаются границы (правая и нижняя).При этом не помогает даже ручная отрисовка границ с помощью тега `<line />`, но это распространяется лишь на нижнюю и правую границы.Как это исправить?

Пользуюсь Google Chrome ,проверил на Firefox там та же ошибка, но что удивительно в Edge все отображается нормально.

[image: При просмотре самого svg]

[image: При просмотре svg вставленного в html]

Code:

```html
<svg width="660" height="660" wiewBox="0 0 660 660" style="border: 2px solid black;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style type="text/css">
    
       .line {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2;
       }
    
       .central {
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-width: 3;
       }
    
       .area {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width:3;
       }
    
       .back-ground {
        fill: white;
       }
    
      </style>
    
     <!--Back-ground-->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="660" height="660" class="back-ground"/>
    
    
     <!--Verticale lines -->
      <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="60" y1="0" x2="60" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="90" y1="0" x2="90" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="120" y1="0" x2="120" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="150" y1="0" x2="150" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="180" y1="0" x2="180" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="210" y1="0" x2="210" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="240" y1="0" x2="240" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="270" y1="0" x2="270" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="330" y1="0" x2="330" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="360" y1="0" x2="360" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="390" y1="0" x2="390" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="420" y1="0" x2="420" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="450" y1="0" x2="450" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="480" y1="0" x2="480" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="510" y1="0" x2="510" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="540" y1="0" x2="540" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="570" y1="0" x2="570" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="600" y1="0" x2="600" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="630" y1="0" x2="630" y2="660" class="line"/>
    
     <!--Horizontale lines -->
      <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="660" y2="30" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="60" x2="660" y2="60" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="90" x2="660" y2="90" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="660" y2="120" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="150" x2="660" y2="150" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="180" x2="660" y2="180" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="210" x2="660" y2="210" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="240" x2="660" y2="240" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="270" x2="660" y2="270" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="300" x2="660" y2="300" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="330" x2="660" y2="330" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="360" x2="660" y2="360" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="390" x2="660" y2="390" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="420" x2="660" y2="420" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="450" x2="660" y2="450" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="480" x2="660" y2="480" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="510" x2="660" y2="510" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="540" x2="660" y2="540" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="570" x2="660" y2="570" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="600" x2="660" y2="600" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="630" x2="660" y2="630" class="line"/>
    
     <!--Central lines -->
      <line x1="330" y1="0" x2="330" y2="660" class="central"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="330" x2="660" y2="330" class="central"/>
    
    
     <!--Point area -->
      <polygon points="30,30 630,30 630,630 30,630" class="area"/>
    
     <!--Image area -->
      
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Хотите я вторым ответом покажу, как этот же результат можно получить кодом в несколько раз меньшим по размерам?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT былобы неплохо :)

Comment: ответ с pattern готов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `wiewBox="0 0 660 660"` правильно написание **v**iewBox="0 0 660 660"
  ошибка всего в одной букве - **v**, но масштабирование работать не
  будет
- Строка в SVG рисуется симметрично относительно осевой линии. Если
  осевая линия проходит по краю svg полотна,то половины толщины линии
  будет не видно. Это надо учитывать и всегда отступать от края.
- Учитывая этот факт, я увеличил `viewBox="-2 -2 664 664"` чтобы вся линия попадала в зону видимости.
- Внешнюю рамку у вас обеспечивал стиль в шапке SVG  -
  `style="border:  2px solid black;"`

  Этот стиль обычно задается  для обозначения границ полотна SVG.
  В вашем случае, раз вы прижались к границам SVG лучше его убрать.
- Для задания внешнего контура вашего чертежа у вас есть `rect`

  `<rect x="0" y="0" width="660" height="660" class="back-ground"/>`
- Добавил стили, чтобы его было видно.

```html
<svg width="660" height="660" viewBox="-2 -2 664 664"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style type="text/css">
    
       .line {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2;
       }
    
       .central {
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-width: 3;
       }
    
       .area {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width:3;
       }
    
       .back-ground {
        fill: white;
       stroke-width:2;
       stroke:#000;
       }
    
      </style>
    
     <!--Back-ground -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="660" height="660" class="back-ground"/> 
    
    
     <!--Verticale lines -->
      <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="60" y1="0" x2="60" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="90" y1="0" x2="90" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="120" y1="0" x2="120" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="150" y1="0" x2="150" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="180" y1="0" x2="180" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="210" y1="0" x2="210" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="240" y1="0" x2="240" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="270" y1="0" x2="270" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="330" y1="0" x2="330" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="360" y1="0" x2="360" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="390" y1="0" x2="390" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="420" y1="0" x2="420" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="450" y1="0" x2="450" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="480" y1="0" x2="480" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="510" y1="0" x2="510" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="540" y1="0" x2="540" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="570" y1="0" x2="570" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="600" y1="0" x2="600" y2="660" class="line"/>
      <line x1="630" y1="0" x2="630" y2="660" class="line"/>
    
     <!--Horizontale lines -->
      <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="660" y2="30" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="60" x2="660" y2="60" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="90" x2="660" y2="90" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="660" y2="120" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="150" x2="660" y2="150" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="180" x2="660" y2="180" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="210" x2="660" y2="210" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="240" x2="660" y2="240" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="270" x2="660" y2="270" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="300" x2="660" y2="300" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="330" x2="660" y2="330" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="360" x2="660" y2="360" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="390" x2="660" y2="390" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="420" x2="660" y2="420" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="450" x2="660" y2="450" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="480" x2="660" y2="480" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="510" x2="660" y2="510" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="540" x2="660" y2="540" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="570" x2="660" y2="570" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="600" x2="660" y2="600" class="line"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="630" x2="660" y2="630" class="line"/>
    
     <!--Central lines -->
      <line x1="330" y1="0" x2="330" y2="660" class="central"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="330" x2="660" y2="330" class="central"/>
    
    
     <!--Point area -->
      <polygon points="30,30 630,30 630,630 30,630" class="area"/>
    
     <!--Image area -->
      
    
    </svg>
```

- Загрузил этот файл на сервер 
  Вызываю его с помощью `<img>`

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/rect4.svg" width="660" height="660" >
```

**Но имейте ввиду, что при таком способе добавления SVG в HTML вы не сможете его стилизовать из внешней таблицы стилей**

О других способах добавления SVG в HTML [более подробно здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047).

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Но я не понимаю почему именно -2 -2 664 664, причину почему -2 я понял но не причину ставить 664 и 664

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук Так нужно было весь прямоугольник отодвинуть от краев канваса SVG  на `2px`  и `664` даёт  расширение просмотрового окна на `4px` Потом всё сжимается в пользовательском окне, который вы видите до `Width="660"` и остается свободное пространство по контуру `2px`

Answer (score 1):

### Использование pattern

Вы используете для получения ячеек вертикальные и горизонтальные линии.
 А если таких ячеек нужно будет нарисовать несколько тысяч?

В этом случае используется `pattern`, в котором указываются размеры одной ячейки `30 X 30 px` и с помощью команды `fill="url(#newpattern)"` заполняется вся фигура

[Подробнее о pattern здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875)

```
<defs>
      <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >

            <g fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="2">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
            </g>
      </pattern>
 </defs>
```

**Ниже пример всего кода:**

```html
<svg width="660" height="660" viewBox="-2 -2 664 664"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style type="text/css">
    
       .line {
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2;
       }
    
       .central {
        stroke: #777;
        stroke-width: 3;
       }
    
       .area {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width:3;
       }
    
       .back-ground {
        fill: white;
     stroke-width:3;
     stroke:#000;
       } 
    
      </style>
    
     <!--Back-ground --> 
  
      <defs>
     <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="2">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
            </g>
      </pattern>
   </defs>
  
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="660" height="660" class="back-ground"/> 
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="660" height="660"  fill="url(#newpattern)"/> 
     <!--Central lines -->
      <line x1="330" y1="0" x2="330" y2="660" class="central"/>
      <line x1="0" y1="330" x2="660" y2="330" class="central"/>
        <!--Point area -->
      <polygon points="30,30 630,30 630,630 30,630" class="area"/> 
        
    </svg>
```

Comment: @Евгений Бабийчук  Не понравился вариант?